# How to connect user-defined bash functions with pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

from some time I really enjoy bash functions. Let's consider the one that computes average from the n-th column of a file:

```
avg () { awk -v c="$2" '{n+=$c;m++} END{print n/m,m}' < "$1"; }
```

Is is possible to rewrite it in such a way that it reads data from pipe? I.e. to use the function in the following:

```
cat data.txt | avg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
avg () { awk -v c="$1" '{n+=$c;m++} END{print n/m,m}'; }
(echo 1 3; echo 2 4; echo 4 6) | avg 2
avg 2 < /tmp/file
```

If you want to keep the API:

```
avg () { (if [ "x$1" = "x-" ]; then cat; else cat $1; fi) | awk -v c="$2" '{n+=$c;m++} END{print n/m,m}'; }
(echo 1 3; echo 2 4; echo 4 6) | avg - 2
avg /tmp/file 2
```